# QML - Filling menu with model items

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I'm trying to fill a `Menu` dynamically from a `ListModel`, but this approach won't work (when I right click the menu won't show anything):

this my menuItems:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ListModel{
    id:menuItems
    ListElement{
        text:"hello1"
    }
    ListElement{
        text:"hello2"
    }
    ListElement{
        text:"hello3"
    }
}
```

and this my menu

```
Menu{
    id:contextMenu
    Repeater{
    model: menuItems
    MenuItem{}

}
```

I even tried to put a an `Instantiator` but the menu won't show anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking in documentation I figured out how to achieve that:

```
Menu {
    id: contextMenu

    Instantiator {
       model: menuItems
       MenuItem {
          text: model.text
       }

       // The trick is on those two lines
       onObjectAdded: contextMenu.insertItem(index, object)
       onObjectRemoved: contextMenu.removeItem(object)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the following information to your question (both as import and as tag) - Which version do you use for your QtQuick.Controls? Is it `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` (tag: `qtquickcontrols`) or `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` (tag: qtquickcontrols2)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the text for every single ListElement to your MenuItem like this:

```
Menu{
    id:contextMenu
    visible: true
    Repeater {
        model: menuItems
        MenuItem {
            text: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

I also added "*visible: true*" to your Menu to show it(I dont know if you are opening it somewhere else).

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the Menu show up or is the Menu filled with empty entries? The answer was tested with Qt 5.9.0

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.9.1, but no errors are shown. the menu just not displaying

Comment: However I figured out how to do it from documentation, I've posted an answer

Comment: If the version used is `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` you need to insert the two lines: `onItemAdded: contextMenu.insertItem(index, item)` and `onItemRemoved: contextMenu.removeItem(item)`. In the older version, `MenuItem` is no `Item`