# QML: Multi-level Menu from ListModel

Tags: qt, qml

I have an example multi-level ListModel:

```
ListModel{
    id: myModel
    ListElement{
        name: "File"
        subItems:[
            ListElement{
                name: "Open"
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Open Recent"
                subItems:[
                    ListElement{
                        name: "Bla.txt"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Save"
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Save as"
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Exit"
            }
        ]
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "Edit"
        subItems:[
            ListElement{
                name: "Undo"
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Redo"
            },
            ListElement{
                name: "Select All"
            }
        ]
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "Help"
        subItems:[
            ListElement{
                name: "About"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which I want to display as Menu. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652525/qml-filling-menu-with-model-items) I know how to iterate model inside of Menu component. But because I have multi-level structure I should check either second level is Menu or MenuItem. Therefore I use Loader and choose which component to load(check if `subItems` of the element is `undefined`):

```
    MenuBar{
    id: menuBar
    Instantiator{
        id: menuBarRepeater
        model: myModel
        onObjectRemoved: menuBar.removeItem( object )
        delegate: Loader{
            sourceComponent: myModel.get(index)["subItems"]? subMenuLoader : menuItemLoader
            onLoaded: {
                item.name = model.name;
                if(myModel.get(index)["subItems"]){
                    item.parentIndex = index;
                    item.model = model
                    menuBar.insertMenu( index, item )
                }else{
                    menuBar.insertItem( index, item )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I need to add one more Instantiator for third level of menu. I could do it recursively, but for example purpose I'll assume that I have max. 3 levels. So the components that will be loaded in code above are:

```
    Component{
    id: menuItemLoader
    MenuItem{
        property var name
        text: name
    }
}

Component{
    id: subMenuLoader
    Menu{
        id: subMenu
        property var name
        property var parentIndex: index
        property var model
        title: name
        Instantiator{
            model: model
            onObjectRemoved: menuBar.removeItem( object )
            delegate: Loader{
                sourceComponent: myModel.get(parentIndex)["subItems"].get(index)["subItems"] ? subMenuLoader : menuItemLoader
                onLoaded: {
                    item.name = model.name;
                    if(myModel.get(parentIndex)["subItems"].get(index)["subItems"]){
                        subMenu.insertMenu( index, item )
                    }else{
                        subMenu.insertItem( index, item )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the model that will be passed to the second level is `QQmlDMListAccessorData` and is not iterable. Is there any way to get children of the Intantiator model item?

Comment: Wait, your title refers to multi-level menus, and you gave a ton of code describing your multi-level structure, but your question is just about getting the children of an Instantiator?

Comment: The menu should be also multi-level, which leads to Instantiator and the problem getting its children. But I'm also opened for any other ideas how to dynamically build a multi-level menu from multi-level structure

Comment: Did you try Instantiator's `objectAt` method?

Comment: Yes, `menuBarRepeater.objectAt(index)` returns `null`

Answer (score 1):

So, the workaround I have found is: instead of passing the model (which has type `QQmlDMListAccessorData`) to `subMenu`, as a second-level `Instantiator` model I used `myModel.get(parentIndex)["subItems"].get(index)`, which addresses to `ListElement`, which for QML has type `QQmlListModel(%index%)` and can be used exactly as its parent (myModel itself)