# QML - Filling menu with MenuItems from model

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I need to fill the QML menu with MenuItems from the model

I found that I can do it like this:

```
Menu {
    id: contextMenu

    Instantiator {
       model: menuItems
       MenuItem {
          text: model.text
       }

       // The trick is on those two lines
       onObjectAdded: contextMenu.insertItem(index, object)
       onObjectRemoved: contextMenu.removeItem(object)
   }
}
```

What is described in this answer:

[QML - Filling menu with model items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652525/qml-filling-menu-with-model-items)

It partially work now, but I get an error:

```
Parameter "object" is not declared
```

And I don't understand which object I should pass to the function contextMenu.insertItem(index, object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the parameters from the signal. Have a read [Signal parameters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters).

```
ListModel {
    id: menuItems
    ListElement { text:"hello1" }
    ListElement { text:"hello2" }
    ListElement { text:"hello3" }
}

Menu {
    id: contextMenu
    visible: true

    Instantiator {
       model: menuItems

       MenuItem {
          text: model.text
       }

       onObjectAdded: function(index, object) {
           contextMenu.insertItem(index, object)
       }
       onObjectRemoved: function(index, object) {
           contextMenu.removeItem(object)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is new syntax in Qt6 that wasn't required in Qt5. That's most likely why older suggestions don't work anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure why the example isn't showing up on https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html, but there's been an example demonstrating how to use Instantiator for a while now: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html#dynamically-generating-menu-items

Answer (score 0):

In this case, because `MenuItem` is a subclass of `Item`, you can use `Repeater` instead of `Instantiator`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: menuItems
        ListElement { text:"hello1" }
        ListElement { text:"hello2" }
        ListElement { text:"hello3" }
    }
    Button {
        id: btn
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: 100
        text: qsTr("Show Menu")
        onClicked: contextMenu.open()
    }
    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        x: btn.x
        y: btn.y + btn.height
        Repeater {
            model: menuItems
            MenuItem {
                text: model.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACV3icjVHBTsMwDL33K6yeNiFFG9x6pOKAxCQ2+IHQWUu0NCmJq3VM+3ecQrOuIIEPif387DzHum6cJ1jTutXVPtNXoSidJe9MyJ7lDuGUAduTDrRyWzTfcTS9LaBG2z4S1iGhkflgkBMEJyDsqMgVGuOWOZz/Zt3+i3U3sL7O+5bI2Ym0N7IplrZSzgfBh/7g8aQpuSf6Ahrp2fuRSJXHApaLRQp7DfAeXv0sf1HuACv+gHye8s6Whv8Q+f2K2zE7EoRr0M7mI8URnegd8RPe9WOIbiwnAke46W+FeqcoZTfYoGT1o87R6ri433Y1KInopOYybF8ton9FuGxp2MT5E9iCplM=)